# Removing lines with the first and the last occurence of a column value

Tags: awk, sed, find-occurrences

I have following file

```
    ID      Score    Other
    ABR     0.98     NBNMSB
    BCG     0.76     NBNMSB
    CVD     0.6      NBNMSB
    BCG     0.9      VSCVA
    CVD     0.56     VSCVA
    ABR     0.9      VSCVA
    CVD     0.7      BAVSC
    BCG     0.4      BAVSC
    ABR     0.5      BAVSC
    AAC     0.1      BAVSC
    ABR     0.8      NBNMSB
    BCG     0.6      NBNMSB
    CVD     0.3      NBNMSB
    BCG     0.7      VSCVA
    CVD     0.0      VSCVA
    ABR     0.1      VSCVA
    CVD     0.5      BAVSC
    BCG     0.8      BAVSC
    ABR     1.0      BAVSC
```

And I want to exclude the first and the last occurrence of a value in column 3 such that I get an output as:

```
ID      Score    Other
BCG     0.76     NBNMSB
CVD     0.56     VSCVA
BCG     0.4      BAVSC
ABR     0.5      BAVSC
BCG     0.6      NBNMSB
CVD     0.0      VSCVA
BCG     0.8      BAVSC
```

Comment: What would you expect if you fed your proposed output back through the filter (i.e. if there's only two of a specific value in column 3, so that literally removing the first and the last occurrence would in fact remove all occurrences)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `tac` (or `gtac`) you can remove the first instances, reverse the file, remove the first (really last) instances and flip the file one last time.

```
$ awk '$3==p;{p=$3}' file1 | tac | awk '$3==p;{p=$3}' | tac
BCG     0.76     NBNMSB
CVD     0.56     VSCVA
BCG     0.4      BAVSC
ABR     0.5      BAVSC
BCG     0.6      NBNMSB
CVD     0.0      VSCVA
BCG     0.8      BAVSC
```

**EDIT**:

Here is a more flexible version. Just set the initial value of `c` to the desired column:

Use column 3:

```
 c=3 && awk -v c=$c '$c==p;{p=$c}' file1 | tac | awk -v c=$c '$c==p;{p=$c}' | tac
```

Use column 4:

```
 c=4 && awk -v c=$c '$c==p;{p=$c}' file1 | tac | awk -v c=$c '$c==p;{p=$c}' | tac
```

Comment: Also how do I go about it if I have 4 columns instead of 3 for instance I have the format as abc 1234 2345 NBNMSB and so on as rows, how do I tweak the above code for unique 4 th column, I tried to replace 3 with 4, is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: Globally changing `$3` to `$4` would be the only change necessary.

Comment: Excellent. Also see the edit for a more flexible version.

Answer (score 4):

In awk you can try this

```
awk 'NR==1
     {last[NR%3]=$3;lastLine[NR%3]=$0;}
     last[(NR-1)%3]==last[(NR-2)%3] && 
           last[(NR-1)%3]==last[NR%3]{print lastLine[(NR-1)%3]}' test
```

which yields the expected output:

```
ID      Score    Other
BCG     0.76     NBNMSB
CVD     0.56     VSCVA
BCG     0.4      BAVSC
ABR     0.5      BAVSC
BCG     0.6      NBNMSB
CVD     0.0      VSCVA
BCG     0.8      BAVSC
```

**Explanation**
1. The NR==1 simple prints the first line.
2. The `{last[NR%3]=$3;lastLine[NR%3]=$0;}` stores the last two lines and the current line in an array (`lastLine`).
3. By `last[(NR-1)%3]==last[(NR-2)%3] && last[(NR-1)%3]==last[NR%3]` we check whether last line has the same value in the third column as the current line and the second last as the last line (i.e., whether they all have the same value in the 3rd column). In this case we print the last line.

Comment: Can you break the code if it is not too much trouble? TIA

Comment: I have provide an explanation. Did you mean that?

Comment: Yes also how do I go about it if I have 4 columns instead of 3 for instance I have the format as abc 1234 2345 NBNMSB and so on as rows, how do I tweak the above code for unique 4 th column, I tried to replace 3 with 4, is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: In this case, just replace each $3 by $4. Don't change the `%3` -- this is necessary to compare just the last three lines (i.e., to correctly discard the first and last occurrence of the specified column's value.)

Comment: I did something like this : awk 'NR==1{last[NR%4]=$4;lastLine[NR%4]=$0;}last[(NR-1)%4]==last[(NR-2)%4]&&last[(NR-1)%4]==last[NR%4]{print lastLine[(NR-1)%4]}' file and yet it didn't spit out any results, I hope I am doing it right.

Comment: awk 'NR==1
     {last[NR%3]=$4;lastLine[NR%3]=$0;}
     last[(NR-1)%3]==last[(NR-2)%3] && 
           last[(NR-1)%3]==last[NR%3]{print lastLine[(NR-1)%3]}' test

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler awk is:

```
awk 'NR == 1; prev != $3 {prev = $3; line = 0; next} 
{if (line) print line; line = $0}' foo.txt | column -t
```

You will get

```
ID   Score  Other
BCG  0.76   NBNMSB
CVD  0.56   VSCVA
BCG  0.4    BAVSC
ABR  0.5    BAVSC
BCG  0.6    NBNMSB
CVD  0.0    VSCVA
BCG  0.8    BAVSC
```

What this does is store the 3rd column and the line in variables called `prev` and `line`, and prints them out if they aren't the first and last occurrences.

Notice that this only takes 1 pass through the file, as opposed to using `tac` and multiple passes.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1p;$!N;/(\S+)\n.*\1$/!d;P;D' file
```

Print the first line reqardless (header line). Read two lines at a time and if the those two lines don't have the same third column delete them both. Otherwise print the first and append the next line and repeat.